# Comparing underlying (derived) types pointed-to by std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++17, unique-ptr, typeid, dynamictype

I am writing unit tests to exercise various code paths involving a factory class.

The factory returns a `std::unique_ptr` to a base type:

```cpp
class Base {};
class Derived1 : public class Base {};
class Derived2 : public class Base {};

std::unique_ptr<Base> Type::Factory(enum rtype) const {
    switch(rtype) {
        case d1: return std::make_unique<Derived1>();
        case d2: return std::make_unique<Derived2>();
        default: return std::make_unique<Derived1>();
    }
}
```

So in the test I want to ensure that the correct type is returned (factories are breeding ground for cut'n'paste bugs).

Is there a way of checking what type is returned?
This: `EXPECT_TRUE(typeid(Derived1), typeid(type.get());` is false because the `type.get()` is that of `Base` and not the `rtype` that was passed in.

Comment: I'd expect that if you do `typeid(*type.get())` then it will check the dynamic type, no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get object's type from pointer to base class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138770/get-objects-type-from-pointer-to-base-class-at-runtime) The 2nd answer says to dereference the pointer as I suggested.

Comment: Having `default` returning a `Derived1` looks scary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This: `EXPECT_TRUE(typeid(Derived1), typeid(type.get());` is `false` because the `type.get()` is that of `Base` and not the `rtype` that was passed in.

`typeid( type.get() )` will get the `typeid` of the base pointer, i.e. the type that `get()` is declared as returning. To get the real dynamic type of the pointed-to object, whatever that may be, you should dereference the pointer:

> `typeid( *type.get() )`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RTTI. The type is erased to `Base` when used.

You can do a dynamic cast to get the proper type, something like:

```
EXPECT_FALSE(dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(type.get()) == nullptr)
```

If dynamic_cast fails (type is not of Derived1) dynamic_cast will return a `nullptr`.